# Open source .NET vector graphics editor

Tags: .net, open-source, vector-graphics, image-editor

Does anyone know of any open source vector editors written in a .NET language?

I know [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) is very popular, but it is written in C++.
The only .NET one I know of is [XDraw](http://xdraw.codeplex.com/), but would like something more active or with more features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) is the best I know. Not exactly a vector editor like Inkscape, but it does provide layers like Photoshop/Gimp, so it can be employed just like Inkscape.

******EDIT**** : Paint.Net is not open source, but is free. (more on this [here](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/57172))

Comment: lol thanks Charlie for that edit :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about it but I just found Creative Docs.net  You can find it here: [www.creativedocs.net](http://www.creativedocs.net/)